# Accessibility of Tomcat during debug

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug Web Service running on Tomcat 7.0 via Axis2 in Eclipse Mars2.

I have started Tomcat inside Eclipse with this arguments:

```
-Xdebug
-Xnoagent
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

I have created the remote debug configuration for my project and started it. Everything seems fine: there's tomcat running and in debug perspective I see my Remote Java Application with some Daemon threads.

But how do I test it? When I try to access tomcat via browser typing "http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/REButils/" it returns 404, Soap UI returns the same?

How do I invoke my service if it's unaccessible?

Comment: Append your application root context to the url; `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/`

Comment: Your service doesnt run at the path ``/``. Axis2 web services usually run at ``/axis2/<something>``.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying this address "http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/REButils?wsdl". Usually, when tomcat runs normally (not with debug options) it returns my wsdl, but when debugging apache allways returns 404

Comment: Check your context root: right click your project, properties, web project settings. The URL you are trying to access should be as follows: "localhost:<port><context-root>". Ensure this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to start Tomcat separately in jpda mode and it worked fine with eclipse remote debugging.

No idea why 404 happenned while starting apache from Eclipse though.